# Convert text to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

please help.

The input text is

```
"['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]"
```

I want to convert to an array

```
['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]
```

it does not work, it adds quotes.

The split() method didn't help, tried the flat() method, but maybe there is something else?

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. WHY do you want this? It looks like a regex pulled apart to never be assembled again. For example this: `' ' '`  - what is the idea to convert `' '` to `' ' '` ? It looks like  a quoted space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Javascript needs special instructions to handle the two types of string

You need to tell it to remove the `'` characters, and to create a regular expression when it sees the `/` character.

This code should do what you want:

```js
const s = "['(', /[1-9]/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, ')', ' ', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, '-', /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/, /\d/]"

const out = s.slice(1, s.length - 1).split(", ").map(e => {
  if (e.startsWith("'")) {
    return e.slice(1, e.length - 1)
  }
  if (e.startsWith("/")) {
    return new RegExp(e.slice(1, e.length - 1))
  }
  throw new Error("Unexpected first character in element " + e)

})


console.log(out)
```

Comment: Well done. But WHY is still the question